# Leaflet TypeError while fetching feature property

Tags: javascript, leaflet

What I am trying to do is to pass specific feature's id to HTML input element on click on that feature.

So far I have this:

```
  function onFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      click: document.getElementById('id_address').value = parseInt(feature.properties.pk)
    });
  }

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "../geojson",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      layer = L.geoJson(response, {
        style: function(feature){
          return {color: "#2c65c1", fillColor: "4774bc", weight: 2};
        },
        onEachFeature: onFeature
      }).addTo(map);
    }
  });
```

But when I click on a feature on the map I got following error in console:
`TypeError: i[n].action.call is not a function`
Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Parsing works fine, so the value to pass to HTML input is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for setting up a Leaflet click event isn't quite right. Also, you need to define the event so it dynamically picks up the required properties of the layer that was clicked on...

```
 function onFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function(e) {
       document.getElementById('id_address').value = parseInt(e.target.properties.pk)
    });
  }
```